# Get the sum of numbers in a for loop

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'm trying to get position value of a string. This works well by printing the integer value of each.

How do I get the sum of the alphabet index in the for loop?

```
val name = "abc".toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
for (element in name) {
    val position = element - 'a' + 1     
}
```

Comment: Which numbers do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in a really concise way with the [`sumBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) function:

```
val input = "abc".toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
val alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
val sum = input.sumBy { element ->
    Log.d("TAG", "${alphabet.indexOf(element) + 1}")
    alphabet.indexOf(element)
}
```

**Edit (after question changed):**

```
val name = "abc".toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
val sum = name.sumBy { element ->
    element - 'a' + 1     
}
```

[Try it out here](https://pl.kotl.in/oHeEQO98_)

Comment: Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: @WebServices Just as a tip: usually you shouldn't change your answer in such a way because it renders the already given answers obsolete. Next time it would be better to add the second code snippet to the original question or ask a new queston. See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Have a variable that you can just add each index to.

```
val input = "abc".toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
val alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var sum = 0
for (element in input) {
    sum += alphabet.indexOf(element)
    Log.d("TAG", "${alphabet.indexOf(element) + 1}")
}
Log.d("TAG", "${sum}")
```

Comment: sum must be `var`

Comment: good spot thanks @GuanHongHuang

Comment: we can also use `let` keyword for sum variable

Comment: Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: @WebServices you have changed the question completely, that should be moved to a separate question as the answers given here now don't make any sense.